# Text that contains the apostroph php

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, sql

I have a serious problem. My app retrieves text from an online database, the problem is that if I put a text in the database that contains the apostrophe in the site displays correctly in the application fails me while synchronizing with the database. I also enabled the magic quote gpc but nothing. How can I fix?

Comment: Please be more coherent about your problem, display specific errors, and show what you've tried.  Also, make sure your encodings are consistent across all languages and databases.

Comment: Can you include more information? Error messages, code, etc would be welcome. Like Blazure said, it may be an encoding problem, but we can't really tell without more information.

Answer (score 1):

First, disable magic_quote_gpc, as the are [deprecated/removed](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php)

Secondly, look at [mysqli_real_escape_string()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) when sending data to database (which I assumed is your 'synchronizing with the database' is).

Comment: According to [this PHP manual page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-magic-quotes-gpc.php), setting magic_quotes_gpc at runtime will not work (if that is the case with yours). If you are using PHP 5.4, it won't work as it is deprecated. See also: [PHP runtime configuration on magic quotes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.magic-quotes-gpc)

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the apostroph like this:

```
INSERT INTO my_table (col1, col2) VALUES (123, 'Hello there''s');
```

Answer (score 0):

use  $user_input = mysql_real_esape_string($user_input)